# Why do I get a null entry when I combine multiple REGEX into a single one?

Tags: python, regex

**I have a string like this:**

```py
textt = '4/20/09 askdaskdkajjasffh haff 11/2/1999 ssaffg gsaff idquyrjdkhfrq 2015'
```

**When I run the following code to extract the dates, in the output I get a list of tuples,my question is: why are there 3 entries in each tuple, and why one is null in each tuple?**

```
regex1 = '(\d{1,2}[/-]\d{1,2}[/-]\d{2,4})'

regex2 = '([1|2]\d{3})'

full_regex = '(%s|%s)' %(regex1, regex2)

re.findall(full_regex,textt)
```

OUTPUT:

```py
[('4/20/09', '4/20/09', ''),
 ('11/2/1999', '11/2/1999', ''),
 ('2015', '', '2015')]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three items in each tuple because your regular expression has three capturing groups (matching parentheses). `regex1` has one group, `regex2` has another group - and you've added a third group around the whole expression when you build `full_regex`.

The reason one group is always empty is because one of the two capture groups in `regex1` and `regex2` is always empty.

If you're trying to capture the full match, you probably only need the capture group in `full_regex` - or, you can ignore the items in the tuple that you don't care about.

Comment: Thank you for your awesome clarification. One more thing, what is the logic behind the order of elements in each tuple (if any), i.e., why does the empty entry appear at different location in each tuple?

Comment: The order within the tuple is the order the capture groups start in your pattern. The first group in your pattern is the outermost group (`full_regex`), the second is `regex1` (full date), and the third is `regex2` (just the year).

Comment: Shouldn't regex2 capture 1999 from 11/2/1999 ?

Comment: Regular expressions will match left-to-right, and will only match each input character one time. You can't match both sides of an alternation (`|`).

Comment: thank you,to my understanding of your comment, if I switch the order of the regex1 and regex2, then since ([1|2]\d{3}) comes first, it should capture 1999 from 11/2/1999, which it doesn't as I tried it.

Comment: That's because the match for `regex1` "wins" at that character when it's matching left-to-right. When the engine tries to match at the `1`, it successfully matches the full date matcher, then skips past the end of the match before resuming. Even if you reverse the order, the year-matcher will fail to match at that character, "losing" to the other matcher.